# Why did my .htaccess stop working with "AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects" error?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a website with WordPress that was running perfectly. For some reason the domain name was unlinked from the site. I linked it again but now the site is not loading any image or css. The `.htaccess` is this (two commented lines that are attempts to fix the issue):

```htaccess
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$ # tried adding this, did not work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) - [L]  # tried adding this, did not work
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The errors I am getting are these:

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.
Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer ...
```

I have no idea why this stopped working (the Apache version or php version *may* have changed but I am not sure of this, this is hosted on a third party supplier not my own server).

Is there something obvious I am missing in the .htaccess file?

Comment: This probably results in a rewriting loop: ->/foo/bar gets rewritten to /blog/index.php which matches the pattern ".", so it gets rewritten to /blog/index.php which matches the pattern ".", so it gets rewritten to /blog/index.php which matches the pattern "." ... Either use the `[END]` flag instead of the `[L]` flag or add an additional condition, or fix the first rule: /blog/index.php will _not_ get matches my `^index\.php` obviously.

Comment: Indeed the cause is a loop. I tried using [END] but it did not work. For some reason this was working stopped working, maybe when creating the new site I changed the base URL. Using information from [this link](https://servebolt.com/help/article/how-to-fix-the-too-many-redirects-error-message/) fixed it, both `.htaccess` and `wp-config.php`.

Comment: Have a try moving that ".htaccess" config file away (rename it). Wordpress will typically try to recrete the file then. Maybe that helps, in case something got modified.